# the application DecRa (process com.Decra) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again

Tags: android

logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Decra/com.Decra.DecRaActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
```

code:

```
    TextView dectv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dec);
    TextView ratv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ra);
    TextView result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button btn=new Button(this);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

When launching the application it Force Closes with the following error:

`the application DecRa (process com.Decra) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.`

And there are no errors in the compiler, So it must be Run-Time errors.
But I don't get what the errors mean! and what I understood is that one of the errors refer to `findViewById`.

Comment: check Activity.java:1637

Comment: Does dectv, ratv and result rally exists? Put a log after each line and see how far it gets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `findViewById()` if you haven't called `setContentView()` beforehand. Just move the TextView initialization lines to the `onCreate()` method as follows:

```
TextView dectv;
TextView ratv;
TextView result;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dectv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dec);
        ratv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ra);
        result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        ...
        ...
    }
```